# I have to print out the 5 future values for this equation

Tags: java, formatting

The code and the calculation are correct i just can not figure out how to format this correctly

```
static void main(String[] args) {

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 String inputString;

  char flag = 'c';


  while(flag =='c' || flag == 'C') {

 System.out.print("Enter your investment amount");

 double futurevalue=input.nextInt ();

 System.out.print("Enter the interest rate (%)");

 double interest = input.nextInt ();

 int i;
 for (i =0; i<=5; i++)
 futurevalue = futurevalue * (1 + (interest/100));

 System.out.printf("Your value is" + futurevalue);

 System.out.printf("Enter c to continue or any other key to quit: ");

 input.nextLine();

 inputString = input.nextLine();

 flag = inputString.charAt(0);
 }
 }
}
```

Period 1%

---

1 505.00

2 510.05

3 515.15

4 520.30

5 525.51

This is what it needs to look like

Comment: Please use System.out.println for new line

Comment: How does it look line now?

Comment: It just has the final number instead of listing all 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for . If you want the answer to be printed per loop

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            futurevalue = futurevalue * (1 + (interest / 100));
            System.out.println((i+1) + " " + futurevalue);                
        }
```

Comment: What I need is for a print out for each of the value for each of the five periods

Comment: Just updated the answer is this what you are looking for  ?